# Oracle REGEXP_LIKE to perform (case,space,special..etc)-insensitive column match with a search string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, special-characters

I have a search keyword that I am looking in a `column` of my table. My search query string may contain special characters like `$`. 
What I want to achieve is: alphanumeric match of my characters in my query string ignoring

1. case of each string,
2. ignoring white space characters and their location in the strings being compared and also
3. ignore any special characters like `” or $ or ^ or & or % etc.`

I have been able to achieve `1` and `2` as follows:

`AND REGEXP_LIKE (columnName, 'searchQueryString', 'ix')`

Here is related [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm)

How can I achieve `1`, `2` and `3`?

Comment: What are special characters? `\W`?

Comment: Rudie..I have listed some of the special characters that I know are creating trouble for me here...however if I can compare alphanumeric i.e A-Za-z0-9 along with `ix` I mentioned in my question, that works for me...thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aafe1/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( val ) AS
          SELECT 'Se ArCh TeRm' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'S$EARCH ^term^' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test
WHERE    LOWER( REGEXP_REPLACE( val,           '(\W|_)+', '' ) )
       = LOWER( REGEXP_REPLACE( 'search_term', '(\W|_)+', '' ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aafe1/5/0)**:

```
|            VAL |
|----------------|
|   Se ArCh TeRm |
| S$EARCH ^term^ |
```

**Query 2**:

Or equivalently (if slightly more verbose):

```
SELECT *
FROM   test
WHERE    LOWER( REGEXP_REPLACE( val,           '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '' ) )
       = LOWER( REGEXP_REPLACE( 'search_term', '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '' ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aafe1/5/1)**:

```
|            VAL |
|----------------|
|   Se ArCh TeRm |
| S$EARCH ^term^ |
```

Comment: Awesome!! just one question, could this: `LOWER( REGEXP_REPLACE( val,           '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '' ) )` be a performance bottleneck...considering we are doing `LOWER + REGEXP_REPLACE` on every value in the column that `SELECT` can possibly fetch?

Comment: Yes, but you can always create a function based index: `CREATE INDEX test__val__idx ON Test( LOWER( REGEXP_REPLACE( val, '(\W|_)+', '' ) ) );` Profile the code though as the index may or may not be beneficial.